# Quotation marks are necessary in this context?

Tags: commas, formal-language, style, formality, quotation-marks

> Moreover, they are causing the disappearing of several **Punos**, which are endemic wetlands of my region vital to the wildlife. Karachi is where my family and I plan to keep living **,** *but due to the current situation* **,** we feel our future is at risk.

1. Quotation marks are necessary in **Punos**? Since it is the specific name of this kind of wetland, I am not sure whether I could use the word **Punos** wihtout them?
2. Is it possible to avoid using the highlighted commas? The commas are those before and after: *but due to the current situation*

Answer (score 1):

I can’t find a definition of “Punos”, so I’m guessing from the context that it’s a non-English word (possibly a transliteration, since you mention Karachi) and also not a proper noun.

If that is correct, the convention is to write the word in lower case italics (*punos*) so readers know it’s not an English word. If the medium you are writing in doesn’t support italics, you can use quotation marks (“punos”) instead.

The first highlighted comma is necessary because it precedes a coordinating conjunction. The second is preferred because it separates the subordinate clause from the independent clause, but both are short enough that you could omit it without causing confusion.

Comment: what do you think about the highlighted commas? are they necessary?. Since the sentence is short, I was thinking about removing that before *but.......*

Comment: @pepo Added that.